# How is jquery used to check for the 'disabled' attribute on an <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `disabled='disabled'` attribute on an `<a>` tag.  How do I test to see if this attribute is on my tag using jquery?  The following code returns `undefined`.  I can see the `disabled` attribute on the tag in firebug and all other attributes on the anchor return successfully using the same syntax.  I realize `disabled` is a custom attribute for an `<a>` tag.

```
$('#anchorID').attr('disabled');
```

Comment: I'm not adding disabled, I just need to check for it's presence.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

```
$('#anchorID').is('[disabled=disabled]')
```

Will return true if `disabled="disabled"` is an attribute for the element.

Comment: This is not always reliable, use `.prop()` (see other answers)

Comment: just `.is('[disabled]')` works for me for any value. i dont know what is different about my situation, but I'm using ASPNet MVC tested with Firefox and chrome as of 2024. Nothing else works except for this.

Answer (score 55):

The new and improved way is to use jQuery's `prop()` function: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1

`$('#anchorID').prop("disabled");`

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

Comment: This is a very informative answer but it did not return the correct value for my field.

Comment: This doesn't actually work on <a> tags. It's good for <input> and <button> tags though. @bardiir's answer is better.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
$('#anchorID').prop("disabled");
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1

Updated: +1 to Ayman Safadi's answer.

Comment: Works for 'checked' not for 'disabled'

Answer (score 2):

An JS alternative:

```
let hasDisabledAttr =  document.querySelector('#anchorID').hasAttribute('disabled');
```

Return `true` or `false`.